# passing a variable from jquery to php with page refresh

Tags: php, jquery

i got a question, how do you pass a variable from jquery to php with a page refresh.
When i click on a button from my menu i would like to pass a variable from jquery to php but because the page refreshes i cant catch it in php, anyone know how to catch it even when the page refreshes? tyvm

Answer (score 1):

Use the query string like this:

```
<a href="somepage.php?myvar=somevalue">Click Me</a>
```

Now in the url you will have `myvar` query string var and you can get its value using php like this:

```
echo $_GET['myvar']; // somevalue
```

Make sure to sanitalize your query string variables.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can avoid refreshing by using links like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="yourFucntionName();">Menu Title</a>
```

Secondly : When your link is clicked then it will get you to a new page which is addressed in its "href" attribute, but your jQuery function is using onclick event to fetch another page (or the same page but with a variable).

In fact, you are making 2 requests but the browser will show you the one which is set by your href attribute,

if you want both refreshing and passing your variable you have to change "href" attribute  instead of passing a variable by jQuery to a new page, like this:

```
<a href="someUrl" onclick="this.href=this.href+'&varName=varValue'">Menu Title</a>
```